# What is another way to say "different levels of interpretation"?

Tags: phrase-request

I am writing a five-paragraph essay about why my assigned book is a classic. One of my paragraph topics is that it offers different levels of interpretation (you can read it just for the thrills of the story, to identify themes, to interpret it for yourself, etc). But I can't say "different levels of interpretation" when I introduce it, refer to it, and conclude it. Suggestions?

Comment: Hi Gus,  per our [FAQ](http://ell.stackexchange.com/help), specifically the ["asking questions"](http://ell.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) section, writing advice is not on topic; you should probably try http://writers.stackexchange.com instead.

Answer (score 1):

One meaning of the word "read" is "interpret".  So you can write:

> The <story> can be read at several levels.

Substitute the type of work (such as "book", "novel", "poem", *et cetera*) in for <story>.  (Or you can substitute the name of the work in for "The <story>".)  You can expand your parenthetical note (about the different levels of interpretation) to provide some or all of the content of the paragraph.

When I am stumped for a good way to say something, I often write out a first draft of what I want to say.  For example, "different levels of interpretation".  After I have finished the rest of my rough draft, I look up one or two key words (such as "level" or "interpret" or "interpretation") in a thesaurus.  In this case, "interpret" has "read" as a synonym.